# How to modify a page title using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using include method to include the menu page on every pages, code below:

```
<!--#include virtual="include/menu/Menu.html"
```

This Menu.html page has a static title `<Title>ABC</Title>`. Note that the Title for current viewing page does not show its Title, but only show the Title for the included Menu.html page, which is "ABC".

Is there a way to change the `<Title><Title>` for the menu page (not the Title on the current viewing page) by using JavaScript, jQuery, or any trick you can think of?

Comment: I expect so. Using jQuery, (not tested) something like `$('title').text('New title')`.

Comment: I just used this technique recently to modify the contents of a `<style>` block, worked for me. Let us know how you get on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('title').text('New title');
```

There is another jQuery method called `html()` but that's only suitable when adding content that must be understood as tags. Since titles cannot contain HTML, `text()` is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just use plain javascript:

```
document.title = "The new title";
```

Comment: tried this work also. Thanks!